# how to progressively update html during several ajax steps especially during file upload

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, file-upload, task-queue

## Long story short

Got javascript code that does 5 ajax steps.

The 2nd and 3rd steps involve file upload. Got a progress bar.

Not sure how to update the progress bar progressively during the 5 steps.

## Long story

The demo is at http://ajaxprogressbar.cloudcontrolled.com/ajaxprogress.html

To execute it, press the “Run the progress bar” button

The code is available at [github](https://github.com/simkimsia/ajaxprogressbars/blob/7e6e9c6be7497e7c865b2ffd0f7c4fe67723d434/ajaxprogress.html)

Basically the ajax process has 5 steps.

step1, 4 and 5 send data to step1.php, step4.php and step5.php respectively.

step2 and step3 are ajax file upload steps.

the sequence should be:

- ONLY after step 1 is done, step 2 and step 3 can be executed at the same time.
- step 4 can ONLY be executed AFTER step 2.
- step 5 can ONLY be executed AFTER all the preceding steps are successful.
- if at any steps, there is any error, the process should be stopped.

## What I wanted to accomplish

1. ONLY after step 1 is done, step 2 and step 3 can be executed at the same time. **(done)**
2. step 4 can ONLY be executed AFTER step 2. **(done)**
3. step 5 can ONLY be executed AFTER all the preceding steps are successful.
4. if at any steps, there is any error, the process should be stopped.
5. update the progress bar 20% after every step **(done)**
6. update the progress bar 1% at a time during step 2 and step 3. **(done)** See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14002393/track-ajax-post-progress-for-fileupload-using-jquery-ajax-and-formdata)
7. refactor the executeProcess to use Q.js instead of jquery when

Note that those marked **(done)** are accomplished. Please see the demo [here](http://ajaxprogressbar.cloudcontrolled.com/ajaxprogress.html).

## What I tried and gotten as a result

- i previously appealed for R6 which I have finally figured out [over here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14002393/track-ajax-post-progress-for-fileupload-using-jquery-ajax-and-formdata)

## What I need

I want to accomplish R3, R4, <s>R6,</s> and R7 without breaking anything else.

<s>**R6 is the most important.**</s>

**R3 is now the most important.**

## FAQs

1. is this your full app?

*No. I did a reduced test case where i stripped out as much un-necessary code to explain my problem without affecting the problem statement as possible.*

*Hence some logic appears to be missing. but rest assured as a demo, there is no bugs. I have tested it.*

*i also simulate the time delay for file upload by putting in `sleep(5)` for the fileupload.php*

## What I will do if I found a solution either here or elsewhere

I will make the solution work as a demo and put it up online.

This is to help other people to learn from my question as well.

Comment: Is this a homework assignment?...

Comment: @b.long no this is not. I apologize if i have confused you. the code is used for a live app.

Comment: @ultranut i apologize. I have removed that part. Basically the most important thing is Requirement 6 without breaking anything else.

Comment: this is a genuine question i am stuck with while developing the live app. I hope that much is clear. I merely stripped out the essential part of the code and turn it into a standalone webpage. once i get a useful answer here or elsewhere, I will put up the solution as well.