# Yii2: How to show file uploading progress?

Tags: file-upload, yii2, progress-bar

I use Yii2 framework. I would like to show file uploading progress. I don't need complex interface with drag-n-drop or preview. Only progress bar and possible 'cancel' button. Could you point me to a simple example? Thanks.

Comment: Are you looking for something to be working with `ActiveForm(JS)` validation along with ajax or just javascript, do have a plot that you are working on so the idea can be clear, as i am currently working on a filemanager plugin for Yii2 which includes ajax based multi-upload functionality along with tracking progress which is integrated with Activeform js and have an extended `FileValidator`, otherwise if you just want to upload a file using ajax with progress see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14002393/track-ajax-post-progress-for-fileupload-using-jquery-ajax-and-formdata)

Comment: @MuhammadOmerAslam, thanks for tip. I made it with ajax and xhr.

Answer (score 1):

Eventually I made it with jQuery ajax.

js:

```
function upload() {
var input = $('#archiveInput');
var files = input.prop('files');
if (files.length > 0) {
    var data = new FormData();
    data.append('archive', files[0]);
    $.ajax({
        url: input.data('upload-url'),
        type: 'POST',
        data: data,
        cache: false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        success: function () {
            alert('Upload Complete');
        },
        xhr: function() {
            var myXhr = $.ajaxSettings.xhr();
            if (myXhr.upload) {
                myXhr.upload.addEventListener('progress', onProgress);
                return myXhr;
            }
        }            
    });
}
}

function onProgress(ev) {
if (ev.lengthComputable) {
    var progress = parseInt(ev.loaded / ev.total * 100, 10); 
    $("#progress .progress-bar").css(
        "width",
        progress + "%"
    );
}
}
```

php controller:

```
public function actionUpload($idSupply)
    {
        $directory = FileHelper::normalizePath(Yii::getAlias('@app') . '/uploads/' . $idSupply);
        if (!is_dir($directory)) {
            FileHelper::createDirectory($directory);
        }
        $fileName = 'archive.zip';
        $filePath = $directory . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $fileName;
        if (is_file($filePath)) {
            unlink($filePath);
        }
        move_uploaded_file($_FILES['archive']['tmp_name'], $filePath);

    }
```

Comment: if the link I mentioned was helpful please close the question as a duplicate so that new users are redirected to the actual answer along with the comments under that answer which are most helpful.